# jQuery .load() fails where ng-include succeeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When I include an html doc using `ng-include` my file loads properly.

```
<div ng-include="'calendar.html'"></div>
```

But because the data passed to that document through my angular controller, I need that file to load again when I push a button.

I tried to use jQuery's `.load()` function to load the page

```
function test(){
  $( "#calendar" ).load( "templates/calendar.html" );
}
```

This loads the page, but the angular elements don't load properly, as you can see in the dev tools screen shot that I took.

[image]

This is supposed to be an element that just pops up over the main page, so I don't want to use the `ui-view` and routing options.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: The proper way to refresh the view in AngularJS is by updating the Model on $scope. You shouldn't be calling jQuery.Load - that is the wrong way to think about doing things the Angular way.

Comment: Also,, there is probably not a direct route in your server to `"templates/calendar.html"` which is why you have to go through angular to get that content.

Comment: @pixelbits So I should still ng-include the file, but just update the model?

Comment: Let's look at calendarCtrl - if you assigned a Model on $scope there, you probably want to do the same thing when you need to update the view.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-include src="CalenderUrl"></div>
```

**Controller:**

`$scope.CalenderUrl="calendar.html";` //write your actual path

If you want to reload calendar.html by any button click. then write like function

```
$scope.reload = function() {
  $scope.CalenderUrl = null;
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.CalenderUrl = "calendar.html";
  }, 0);
}
```